# How to delegate room liveData by mutableStateOf

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose

I want to delegate the room liveData as the default value of mutableStateOf.

```
// state -- can work with compose such as add or remove
var items: List<Item> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    private set

// room -- persist store the data
val items: LiveData<List<Item>> = itemDao.getAll()

// state(room)? -- get the persistence data and work with compose
val items: List<Item> by mutableStateOf(itemRepository.items.value)  // not work
```

Answer (score 0):

By refer to other people's open source project, I find the work around.

```
// compose
@Composable
fun Items(
  viewModel: MainViewModel
) {
  val items: List<Item> by viewModel.items.observeAsState(listOf())
  ...
}
```